# How to pass table to a function without first element?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to create a function that receives a table of strings and parses the table to other function based on its first element.

**My Code :**

```
fruits = {}

function addToFruits(t)
print(#t)
end

function parseTable(t)
  if t[1] == "fruits" then
    addToFruits(table.remove(t, 1)) --pass only {"apple", "banana"}
  end
end

parseTable({"fruits", "apple", "banana"})
```

**The Result I get :**

> 6

**The Result I expect :**

> 2

How to properly parse the table without the first element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value from `table.remove` is the removed element ("fruits" )

The object is a string and has length 6, explaining the answer your code is getting.

If you wanted the right answer 2, then the following code will do it.

```
fruits = {}

function addToFruits(t)
  print(#t)
end

function parseTable(t)
  if t[1] == "fruits" then
    table.remove(t, 1)
    addToFruits( t ) --pass only {"apple", "banana"}
  end
end

parseTable({"fruits", "apple", "banana"})
```

Obviously this damages the original table, and depending on use, would need either a table copy - there are various articles on that.

In preference, I would use a structure such as ...
`message = { type = "fruits", data = { "apple", "banana" } }`

Allowing for the data to be separated from the message type.

The new code would look like....

```
fruits = {}

function addToFruits(t)
   print(#t)
end

function parseTable(t)
  if t.type == "fruits" then
    addToFruits( t.data ) --pass only {"apple", "banana"}
  end
end
message = { type = "fruits", data = { "apple", "banana" } }
parseTable( message )
```

Answer (score 3):

The table.remove function removes (and returns) an element from a given position in an array. [ref](http://The%20table.remove%20function%20removes%20(and%20returns)%20an%20element%20from%20a%20given%20position%20in%20an%20array)

```
function parseTable(t)
  if t[1] == "fruits" then
      local removed = table.remove(t, 1)
      print(removed) -- fruits
      addToFruits(t) -- fruits removed and will pass {"apple", "banana"}
  end
end
```

The answer 6 was the length of "fruits" which `table.remove(t, 1)` will return